# WPF TabControl preserve selected tab when SelectedObject changed

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I'm using WPF TabControl and got a simple question (I hope).

I got a List of items, and for each item there are details displayed in a TabControl with 3 Tabs.

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedLibrary.DetailViewModels}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

  <TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type provider:PropertyPageViewModel}">
      <dxprg:PropertyGridControl
        ReadOnly="True"
        ShowProperties="WithPropertyDefinitions"
        ExpandCategoriesWhenSelectedObjectChanged="True"
        ShowCategories="Hidden"
        ShowMenuButtonInRows="False"
        ShowToolPanel="False"
        ValueColumnWidth="2*"
        ShowSearchBox="False"
        SelectedObject="{Binding FunctionBaseData.Function, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Name" Header="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.PropertyGridHeaderName}" />
        <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Id" Header="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.PropertyGridHeaderId}"   />
        <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Type" Header="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.PropertyGridHeaderType}" />
        <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Category" Header="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.PropertyGridHeaderCategory}"  />
        <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="Version" Header="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.PropertyGridHeaderVersion}"/>
        <dxprg:PropertyDefinition Path="LastModified" Header="{x:Static fpProperties:Resources.PropertyGridHeaderLastModified}" />
      </dxprg:PropertyGridControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type provider:PreviewPageViewModel}">
      <TextBlock Text="PreviewPage"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type provider:CodePageViewModel}">
      <TextBlock Text="SourcePage"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

This works.

When the user selects another item in the list the `SelectedObject` of my Tab changes, thats fine.
But the selected tab also changes, I want the selected Tab to stay the same as for the item before.

I Tried this `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"`, but that wouldnt help. Please tell me theres a property I can easily set for the WPF TabControl.

Thanks

Comment: can you also provide your ViewModel code?

Comment: There is `SelectedObject` in your sample markup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an XAML-only way to do this. All the "selected" properties (`SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex`, etc.) will always reset when the `ItemsSource` changes.

You'll need to record the value of `TabControl`'s `SelectedIndex` before the change, then set it back to that value after the change. Without seeing the rest of your code, I couldn't tell you exactly where to do those steps.  The recording could be done in `SelectedLibrary.DetailViewModels` as part of the setter, or in whatever code that does the setting. Resetting the `SelectedIndex` could be done on `SelectionChanged`.